# Untyped Sqlite columns with F# SqlProvider

Tags: sqlite, f#, type-providers, fsharp.data.typeproviders

Sqlite supports untyped columns, i.e. columns where the type is omitted in the `CREATE TABLE`statement and where you can insert any value.

Is there a way to access such columns using the `SqlDataProvider` from `FSharp.Data.Sql`?

It seems that columns like this are simply not visible in the generated types. But maybe there is some work-around or a special option?